# How to develop an iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I want to develop an ebook application for iPhone.
I'm new to iPhone developement, so don't have much idea about how to proceed.
What I know is, I need the following:-

- iPhone SDK
- Intel Mac running mac OS X
- Xcode (?)

Please indicate is that correct and how I can proceed to build an ebook application.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest reading up and programming a few simple apps before attempting a "production" app -- it will improve the quality of the initial released one tremendously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Probably start from basic tutorial to create a simple [cocoa application](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html).**

Once you figure out how to connect create UI, wire code to UI and run it on simulator you can move on to finding the specifics of your ebook app.

[This is another good starting point](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html).

[Mac OS X Reference Library.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/#)

I assume you will need to download the ebook from network, parse it, display. So look for how you accomplish each task.

Once you figure it out you will apply to get developer license so that you can load up your application on handset and test it before submitting it to App Store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.  Then start the software development life cycle:

```
Requirements Engineering -> Design -> Implementation -> Testing -> Maintenence
```

Comment: assuming a plan driven development cycle.

Comment: You might want to include offshoring to help cut down on costs.

Comment: @Matthew Ha yes, assuming a lot of things :D